# How to recreate typography in Old Bollywood posters?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, typography, gradient

Can someone help me to create text in Photoshop that is similar to the sort of text that is in this old Bollywood movie's poster. It looks like text in the gap between the arcs of a hyperbola. Also how to achieve the gradient in the text?

[image: Observe text reading "Mughal-e-Azam"]

Answer (score 2):

The following should work with most versions of Photoshop since CS4 onwards.

1. Type some text.
2. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on Mac) and stretch the text vertically.
3. Right click the text layer, and choose `Convert to Smart Object`
4. Click `Edit` > `Transform` > `Warp`
5. Deform the image like this example

[image]

The "gradient" isn't a gradient - it looks like someone has added a flame effect on the letters.  There are tutorials on the internet available for that.

Answer (score 1):

Seemingly the warping already is given, so I add one easy method for coloring.

Have three layers:

- a black layer
- a photo of fire or other colored texture
- your text as rasterized, warped, in high resolution and having the wanted solid base color.

[image]

(I know that the text is meaningless nonsense and the kerning of the hyphens is awful. I'll fix the hyphens at the end. )

Select the empty exterior of the text with the magic wand and invert the selection to get the text fully selected. Using that selection Select a piece of fire and paste it as a new layer. Be sure to paste in place!

[image]

Next create a layer mask to the fire text layer and paint a mask manually or insert a black to white gradient to hide partially the fire. Here the mask is painted. First the mask was full white and adding black hided the fire:

[image]

Make again the selection with the text. Now copy and paste in place as new layer a piece of the black layer. Duplicate the black text layer at least twice and drag all of them to different sizes and places. The purpose is to approximate a black extrude of the text:

[image]

Merge the black texts and manually fix the black extrude to the final shape. You need the polygonal lasso tool, the eraser and a brush for painting black. Make lasso selections for easy painting and erasing.

The result:

[image]

There surely exist some add-on to Photoshop for easy 3D text effects. Unfortunately I have not one. Layer style Bevel & Emboss is not useful in this case due the curved shape.

The result must be seen also on some background and the hyphens must be fixed for a judgement:

[image]